# How can I retrieve this type of line of code from a foreach loop statement using PHP and Jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I retrieve this line of echo code from my php file to my jquery and I am expecting rows of values.

my php file

```
foreach($stmt as $warrior){
            echo '<td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td>';
        }
```

my js script

```
<script>
    function createWarrior() {
        $.post( "create_warrior.php", { 
        "wname": $("#txtWname").val(),
        "wtype": $("#txtWtype").val()           
        }, 
        function(msg){
            //What should I put here
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

my html code

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Warrior</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Warrior ID</th>
            <th>Warrior Name</th>
            <th>Warrior Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            //the output should be here
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add tags `<tr>` at the beginning and end

```
foreach($stmt as $warrior){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td></tr>';
        }
```

the result will be

```
<tr><td>warrior_id_1</td><td>warrior_name_1</td><td>warrior_type_1</td></tr>
<tr><td>warrior_id_2</td><td>warrior_name_2</td><td>warrior_type_2</td></tr>
....
```

this answer you need to get in the js and append to html:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'create_warrior.php',
    //Send data to php if you need. In php use $_POST['wname'] to read this data.
    data: {wname: $("#txtWname").val(),wtype: $("#txtWtype").val() },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#dataTable').append(data);
    }
  });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id = "dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Warrior</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Warrior ID</th>
            <th>Warrior Name</th>
            <th>Warrior Type</th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it works but I call the event on my onclick event It still shows that old values? how can I clear it or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like (note the added `<tr></tr>`)

```
foreach($stmt as $warrior){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$warrior['warrior_id'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_name'].'</td><td>'.$warrior['warrior_type'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

with

```
<script>
function createWarrior() {
    $.post( "create_warrior.php", { 
    "wname": $("#txtWname").val(),
    "wtype": $("#txtWtype").val()           
    }, 
    function(msg){
        $('#mytable').append(msg);
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

and

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Warrior</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Warrior ID</th>
        <th>Warrior Name</th>
        <th>Warrior Type</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

should work I believe, didn't try it.